# jupyter の config ディレクトリ (`~/.jupyter`) をホーム直下以外に指定するには？

Tags: jupyter-notebook

jupyter notebook サーバーを立ち上げるにあたって、 `jupyter notebook --generate-config` を行うと、 `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` が作成され、 jupyter notebook サーバーの設定をそこで記述できます。

今、 VPN 上のサーバーで jupyter を立ち上げるにあたって、このディレクトリの場所を変更したくなりました。

#### 質問

jupyter notebook の設定ディレクトリを、デフォルト(`~/.jupyter`) から変更するのはどうやったら実現できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unix系ならば環境変数のJUPYTER_CONFIG_DIRに参照先のディレクトリパスを記述すれば良いようです。
記述は ver 4.1 のドキュメントのようですが、最新でも変わっていなければ使えるでしょう。

[jupyter_notebook_config.pyの読み込み先を変更する](https://himenon.github.io/python/jupyter/change-jupyter-config-dir/)

[Common Directories and File Locations](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html)

> ***Configuration files***
>   Config files are stored by default in the ~/.jupyter directory.
>
> **JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR**
>   Set this environment variable to use a particular directory, other than the default, for Jupyter config files.
>
> Besides the user config directory mentioned above, Jupyter has a search path of additional locations from which a config file will be loaded. Here’s a table of the locations to be searched, in order of preference:
>
> Unix
>   JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR
>   {sys.prefix}/etc/jupyter/
>   /usr/local/etc/jupyter/ /etc/jupyter/
>
> Windows
>   %PROGRAMDATA%\jupyter\
>
> To list the config directories currrently being used you can run the below command from the command line:
>
> ```
> jupyter --paths
> ```

関連
[Changing the Location of the Jupyter Config Directory #46](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_core/issues/46)

---

ちなみに他にこんな記事があって、実際に適用可能ならばコマンドラインで指定可能のようです。
[Command line for Jupyter notebook](http://www.xavierdupre.fr/app/ensae_teaching_cs/helpsphinx/command_lines/ipython_notebook.html)

> –config= (JupyterApp.config_file)
>   Default: “” Full path of a config file.
>
> **Examples**
>
> ```
> jupyter notebook                            # start the notebook
> jupyter notebook --certfile=mycert.pem      # use SSL/TLS certificate
> jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=<folder>    # change the notebook folder
> ```